# Python how to get the count of each time a new parameter value is passed to function

Tags: python-3.x, function

> Python function:

```
def set_console_log(self, log_value):
    self.logger.debug(log_value)
```

> Each time this function is called log_value keeps on changing, so is
> there a way to keep the count of each time log_value is set with values during this function call.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `class` then use a class variable.

**Ex:**

```
class MyClass:
    # Count
    some_count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        .....

    def set_console_log(self, log_value):
        MyClass.some_count += 1
        
a = MyClass()
a.set_console_log("A")
a.set_console_log("B")
print(a.some_count)    # --> 2
```

Comment: As this function is used across the application to log the logs into a log_file will this solution  work for this scenario?